# PHP Registration form - uploading images and making numbers in form

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, registration

I want to make a registration form where I can attach image and write when his subscribe ends (In numbers or date)

This is my code

```
    if (isset($_POST['username'])){
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];
 $username = stripslashes($username);
 $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
 $email = stripslashes($email);
 $email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
 $password = stripslashes($password);
 $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
 $trn_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
 $expira = $_Post[''];
 $query = "INSERT into `users` (username, password, email, trn_date,expira) VALUES ('$username', '".md5($password)."', '$email', '$trn_date', '$expira')";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 if($result){
 echo "<div class='form'><h3>You are registered successfully.</h3><br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
 }
 }else{
?>
```

And this is submit form

```
    <form name="registration" action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" required />
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
<input type="text" name="expira" placeholder="Data de Expirare al cardului" required />
<input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />
</form>
```

$expira = $_Post[''] is the date when subscribe ends. It's in input too.

But for image I did not do anything because I did not find any tutorial for that.

Comment: You want to output the subscription end date as an image, is that correct?

Comment: No. I am creating accounts.  No one has acces to registration. 


When I register a new account, I want to put a date (23.04.2013 or something like that)  and that shall be saved in mysql database. 


When login - in,  I will make a page where it will show Subscribe Expiratino Date:  23.04.2013. 



And I want to make a "profile picture".  I attach to registration a picture of user, and when he logs in it will appear on his page that picture.

Comment: So you want to add an image uploader? There are really tons of tutorials online for that. For example [this one](https://davidwalsh.name/basic-file-uploading-php). Just search for PHP file uploader.

Comment: I want to upload myself a photo, to be saved in database, and later I want to use in HTML to show as a profile picture. 

There will be a picture per account. 

I don't want to give acces to upload image only to registration page. 



Beside that I did not find how to put numbers in registration part.